# Google CodeJam Bathroom Stalls 2017 Qualification Round large dataset error

Tags: c#, tree, long-integer, biginteger

I'm trying to solve the [Google CodeJam 2017 "Bathroom Stalls" problem C](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/3264486/dashboard#s=a&a=2) -  the solution is provided in the link, and my C# code below works great on small1 & 2 sets. The large set looks solved OK, but the online judge fails it as **incorrect**. Does anyone have ideas why? I tried using `ulong`s, I tried to detect overflows, I ran comparisons with small sets via bruteforce to find the same solutions.

```
    private string SeatTreeSkip(ulong n, ulong k)
    {
        var q = new SortedSet<ulong>();
        q.Add(n);
        var c = new Dictionary<ulong,ulong>();
        c[n] = 1;
        for (ulong i = 0; i < n; )
        {
            ulong p = q.Last();
            ulong x0 = (ulong)Math.Ceiling((p - 1) / 2.0);
            ulong x1 = (ulong)Math.Floor((p - 1) / 2.0);
            if (p - 1 < 0)
                p = p;
            i += c[p];

            if (i < 0 || x0 < 0 || x1 < 0)
                throw new Exception("overflow");
            if (i >= k)
                return x0 + " " + x1;

            q.Remove(p);
            q.Add(x0);
            q.Add(x1);
            if (!c.ContainsKey(x0)) c.Add(x0, 0);
            if (!c.ContainsKey(x1)) c.Add(x1, 0);
            c[x0] += c[p];
            c[x1] += c[p];
        }
        throw new Exception("k is over");
    }
```

Input snippet:

```
4 2
5 2
6 2
1000 1000
1000 1
500000000000000000 249999999999999999
1000000000000000000 500000000000000000
999999999999999999 423539247696576511
3 2
500000000000000000 144115188075855872
1000000000000000000 1
```

Output snippet:

```
Case #1: 1 0
Case #2: 1 0
Case #3: 1 1
Case #4: 0 0
Case #5: 500 499
Case #6: 1 0
Case #7: 1 0
Case #8: 1 1
Case #9: 0 0
Case #10: 1 1
Case #11: 500000000000000000 500000000000000000
```

Comment: It would appear that Case # 5 and Case # 11 should have similar answers. Why would one of them have 500 499 and the other equal numbers?

Answer (score 0):

As @Jo says in the comment, your answer to Case #11 is incorrect (it should be:

`Case #11: 500000000000000000 499999999999999999`

)

I suspect that the error is in the formula you are using to split the integers into subproblems (you may be losing precision when casting back again to `ulong`).

You can fix this problem by avoiding the floating point division by 2.0 and shifting the value instead. Here's how I solved it (in Python):

```
def split(value):

    n = value >> 1

    return (n, n-1) if value % 2 == 0 else (n, n)
```